# PHP Flat object to hierarchical object

Tags: php, object, hierarchical, flat

There have been a few questions already on the topic, but they typically relate to turning hierarchal objects into flat objects, a non-issue for me. However, I am currently completely stumped in creating a hierarchal object from a flat object.

Assume the following simplified database table

```
id | parent 
 1 |   0
 2 |   1 
 3 |   1
 4 |   3
 5 |   4
```

After a database query, the following object is returned:
$queryResult:

```
[{id:1, parent:0}, 
 {id:2, parent:1}, 
 {id:3, parent:1}, 
 {id:4, parent:3},
 {id:5, parent:4}]
```

What I am trying to accomplish through a recursive method is creating an object identical to the following:

```
[{
   id:1,
   children:[
      {id:2},
      {id:3,
          children:[
              {id:4, 
               children:[
                  {id:5}
               ]
              }
          ]
      }  
   ]
}]
```

I have some beginnings, but my brain just can't keep up anymore...
Does anyone have any suggestions on a recursive function that returns the desired object?
Below is the dirty piece of code (think doodling) that I currently have. It functions properly, until the function is called recursively and it will start duplicating entries.

```
function CreateObject($object, $new = array()){

    for($i = 0; $i < count($object); $i++){
        $found = false;
        foreach($object[$i] as $key => $value){
            if ($key == 'parent'){
                if ($value == 0){
                    array_push($new, $object[$i]);
                } else {
                    //push into parent
                    for($j = 0; $j < count($new); $j++){
                        foreach($new[$j] as $k => $v){
                            if ($k == 'id' && $v == $value){
                                $found = true;
                               
                                if (property_exists($new[$j], 'children')){
                                    array_push($new[$j]->children, $object[$i]);
                                } else {
                                    $new[$j]->children = array();
                                    array_push($new[$j]->children, $object[$i]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (!$found){
                            foreach($new[$j] as $k => $v){
                                if ($k == 'children'){
                                    CreateObject($object, $v);
                                }
                            }
                           break;
                        }  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    
    return $new;
}


$hierarchalObject = CreateObject($flatObject);
```

With a quickly created object of: (this results in the exact same object returned by the query)

```
$flatObject = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 1),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 2),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 2),
    );

$flatObject = json_decode(json_encode($flatObject));
```

returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "parent": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "parent": 2
                    },
                    {      //DUPLICATES HERE
                        "id": 5,
                        "parent": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "parent": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to be as complete as possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated for my aching brain.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to C3iG3's answer, the following function works perfectly for my situation. It's a very slightly modified version of C3iG3's answer to include all of the node's properties, as well as not include a children property if it's empty.

```
<?php
        function unflatten ( $data )
        {
            /* Create new node objects */
            function create_new_node ( $o ) {
                return new class ( $o ) {
                    public $id;

                    public function __construct ( $o ) { 
                        //get all properties and assign to node
                        foreach($o as $key => $value){
                            if ($key != 'parent'){
                                $this->$key = $value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }            
        
            $roots = array(); // store root nodes
            $nodes = array(); // store all nodes
        
            foreach ( $data as $o ) 
            {
                $node = isset( $nodes[$o->id] ) ? $nodes[$o->id] : null; // check if node was already created
        
                if ( !$node ) {
                    $node = create_new_node($o);
                }
        
                $nodes[$o->id] = $node; // keep track of node
        
                if ( $o->parent ) // node has a parent
                {
                    if ( !isset( $nodes[$o->parent] ) ) { // if parent node was not already created
                        $nodes[$o->parent] = create_new_node( $o->parent );
                    }
                    $nodes[$o->parent]->children[] = $node; // add node to parent
                } else {
                    $roots[] = $node;
                }
            }
        
            return $roots;
        }
?>
```

Comment: The easiest thing I can think of would be to set the index for each element in the child array as the id to avoid duplicates. so `"children": [5 => {id: 5, parent: 2}, 6 => {id: 6, parent: 2}, ... ]`. Then instead of using `array_push`, I think you can just set the value like `$new[$j]->children[$k] = $object[$i];`

Comment: Thank you for the insight  WOUNDEDStevenJones, it ended up being the wrong approach all together.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not well suited for a recursive solution. The reason for this is primarily because of how your data is structured. Each of your objects tracks its parent, rather than its children.

There are no obvious starting points for a recursive function. If you start at a parent object, you do not know what children to tie to the parent, so there is no way to divide the problem (cannot recurse down the hierarchy). You could recurse up the hierarchy (by following the parents), but since this does not divide the problem in any way, it does not benefit from being written recursively. You certainly can write a recursive solution that creates nodes, traverses the existing hierarchy, and inserts them, but this would become inefficient for large hierarchies.

Instead, this problem is better suited for an iterative solution.

```
<?php

function unflatten ( $data )
{
    /* Create new node objects */
    function create_new_node ( $id ) {
        return new class ( $id ) {
            public $id;
            public $children = array();
            
            public function __construct ( $id ) { $this->id = $id; }
        };
    }

    $roots = array(); // store root nodes
    $nodes = array(); // store all nodes

    foreach ( $data as $o ) 
    {
        $node = isset( $nodes[$o->id] ) ? $nodes[$o->id] : null; // check if node was already created

        if ( !$node ) {
            $node = create_new_node( $o->id );
        }

        $nodes[$o->id] = $node; // keep track of node

        if ( $o->parent ) // node has a parent
        {
            if ( !isset( $nodes[$o->parent] ) ) { // if parent node was not already created
                $nodes[$o->parent] = create_new_node( $o->parent );
            }
            $nodes[$o->parent]->children[] = $node; // add node to parent
        } else {
            $roots[] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $roots;
}

$queryResult = json_decode('[{"id":1, "parent":0}, {"id":2, "parent":1}, {"id":3, "parent":1}, {"id":4, "parent":3}, {"id":5, "parent":4}]' );

echo json_encode( unflatten( $queryResult ) );
```

This will generate the following structure:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "children": []
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3,
        "children": [{
            "id": 4,
            "children": [{
                "id": 5,
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

This solution requires a single pass over the original set of objects and attaches them to their parents in constant time. There is some slight overhead by having to keep track of all existing nodes in the `nodes` array.

This solution can be re-written to be recursive but is going to end up modeling a looping structure (which is a good indicator that the problem is better suited to be written iteratively).

Comment: THANK YOU! I was getting more and more stumped... I was using a recursive function to read the hierarchal output, which works great, so I thought the opposite also needed a recursive function. I have slightly modified your code to make it work if the node has additional properties as well.